# Is $53\cdot 83\cdot109+40\cdot66\cdot96$ prime or composite?

Tags: calculus, number-theory

> Let $$A=53\cdot 83\cdot109+40\cdot66\cdot96$$
>   Is this number prime or composite?

I'm sure it's a composite number. But I do not know how to prove it.

Comment: It's composite...by brute force, $149$ is a factor.  Do you have any reason to think that there's a better method than force?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$abc+(149-c)(149-b)(149-a)=149 (a b+bc+ca-149 a-149 b-149 c+22201)
$$

Comment: Nice observation +1. Easier to see as $abc+(-a)(-b)(-c)=0 \pmod {149}$.

Comment: I'm curious...did you spot this from the original form or did you get $149$ as a factor directly and then find this as an explanation?

Comment: @Macavity: Nice. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @lulu: To be honest, the latter.

Comment: Oh, it's still a good observation (+1).  I, by contrast, just asked Mathematica to find the factor for me, and then I stopped.

Answer (score 2):

Let's factor further $A=149\times 4919$. So $A$ is composite.

Answer (score 1):

Given number is $A=53\cdot 83\cdot109+40\cdot66\cdot96=  732931$

No, $732931$ is not a prime number, it is a composite number.

> Why $732931$ is not a prime number?

Because $732931$ has divisors rather than $1$ and itself. $732931$ can be divided by $149$ and $4919$.

Prime factorization of $732931$ (list of divisors):

$149\cdot4919$

The next prime number of $732931$ is $732943$

The previous prime number of $732931$ is $732923$.

Comment: You should put a dot (\cdot) between those two factors two lines before the last one.

Comment: @Mithless I've no idea what you just asked, sorry.

Comment: @MithleshUpadhyay: In the United States, a "full stop" (which we call a "period") does not represent multiplication. Instead, we use a "centered dot" which is shown by "\cdot" in MathJax.

Comment: @Joanpemo, I've edited that. Thanks for notice that.

Comment: @Rory Daulton Period?? It means full stop?

Comment: @N.S.JOHN: Basically, yes, though there are other meanings of both phrases. See the first paragraph of [this web page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_stop) to see the equivalence.